# Highly Opinionated Goal App

Tags: productivity, iphone-app

Reaching goals and creating habits is probably one of the most difficult and most rewarding endeavors.  I'm looking for an app that I believe might exist, unfortunately each feature is subtle but important and the number of goal apps to comb through is enormous.  Has anyone found an app with the following set of very opinionated features:

1. Limits the number of goals to 1 or 2 and the entire interface is optimized for a short list of goals.
2. Goals must be stated in the form of X to Y by WHEN. For example: Go from a 34 inch waste to a 30 inch waste by December 31, 2015. The goal must be plotted and as I update my progress it must clearly shows whether I'm on track or off track. Winning -vs- Losing.
3. I should be able to define at least 2 tactics or habits per goal that is stated as a weekly target or sum. For example, jog for 2 hours weekly. I should be able to input tactic events and they should sum weekly to see If I'm hitting a weekly target. I should easily be able to see my last 12 weeks of tactics performance and the app should use a point and gaming system to encourage consecutive tactic wins.
4. I should be able to invite friends who can review my tactic and goal performance, they are nudged to keep me completing and measuring my tactics via email alerts.